# Central limit theorem measurment error

Tags: probability, statistics, central-limit-theorem

We have a  laser that measures length. Average measurement error is 0 cm and deviation of error is 1cm. We repeat measurements 20 times and calculate new average. What is the probability that error is below 0.5 cm.

The solution says it's 0.975, but i can't get the same result.

What I tried is this: P(X<=0.5) = fi(-0.5/sqrt(20)) + 0.5. Where fi is the error function. I would like to know what is wrong with my attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Each observation is $X_i \sim \mathsf{Norm}(0, 1).$

Mean of $n=20$ observations is $\bar X \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 0, \sigma=1/\sqrt{20}).$

You seem to be trying to find $P(\bar X < 0.5),$ or perhaps $P(\bar X < -0.5).$

Focusing on the 'error' rather than the 'value' $\bar X$ itself, I think you are intended to compute 
$$P(|\bar X - 0| < .5) = P(-.5 < \bar X < .5) =
P\left(\frac{-.5-0}{1/\sqrt{20}}<\frac{\bar X-0}{1/\sqrt{n}} <\frac{.5-0}{1/\sqrt{20}}\right)\\
= P(-2.236 < Z < 2.236) = 0.9746154.$$

*Note:* You mention the CLT in your title. Even if $X_i$ are not exactly
normally distributed, the CLT "suggests" that $\bar X$ is more nearly normal
than the data. Taking the limit as $n \rightarrow \infty,$ the CLT says that
$\bar X$ is exactly normal (provided the population distribution of the
$X_i$ has finite variance). However, for many physical measurements $n = 20$ is a large enough sample for $\bar X_{20}$ to be essentially normal. [For example, if
$X_i \sim \mathsf{Unif}(-1, 1),$ then it is very difficult to
distinguish the distribution of $\bar X_{20}$ from a normal distribution.]

Comment: I don't understanx how did you get 1/20. If we have normal distribution N(0,1) and we want sum of 20 of them N(0*20,sqrt(20))?

Comment: If $n$ observations $X_i \sim NORM(0, \sigma),$ then $Var(\bar X) = \sigma^2/n$ and $SD(\bar X) = \sigma/\sqrt{n},$ so $\bar X \sim NORM(0, \sigma/\sqrt{n}).$ In my notation the second argument of NORM is the SD. Also, note we are dealing with $\bar X = \frac 1n \sum_i X_i,$ not $\sum_i X_i.$